# How do I remove paired Bluetooth devices on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want my app could remove paired bluetooth devices. Becaues if device paried with iPhone, the device couldn't used for another device.
I tried  CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection, but it doesn't work. they're still paired.

Or there's some other app still connected this server?

iPhone5,iOS7

Answer (score 9):

You cannot unpair a device programmatically in iOS.

The `cancelPeripheralConnection` is only to disconnect your apps connection to the device.

> **Discussion**
>
> This method is nonblocking, and any `CBPeripheral` class commands that
>   are still pending to peripheral may or may not complete. Because other
>   apps may still have a connection to the peripheral, canceling a local
>   connection does not guarantee that the underlying physical link is
>   immediately disconnected. From the app’s perspective, however, the
>   peripheral is considered disconnected, and the central manager object
>   calls the centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error: method of its
>   delegate object.

Comment: Maybe it is possible with private APIs if the app is not targeted for the App Store: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager.h

Answer (score 2):

`cancelPeripheralConnection:` should work.

When you connect with a peripheral (Bluetooth device) probably you are doing it in:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    [centralManager connectPeripheral: peripheral
                              options: nil];
}
```

It is important to do it keeping the `peripheral` and the `centralManager` as a @property:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) CBPeripheral *connectingPeripheral;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
```

Then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Starting Up a Central Manager
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self 
                                                               queue:nil
                                                             options: nil];
}
```

And:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral;

    [centralManager connectPeripheral: self.connectingPeripheral
                              options: nil];
}
```

Then when the connection is successfully stablished, the central manager object calls: `centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:`

After that you can call in your code:

```
[self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:self.connectingPeripheral];
```

Comment: IMO you are answering a question on how to 'disconnect' a peripheral from the phone, not how to 'unbond' a peripheral from the phone. Those are two different cases.