# Is it possible to disconnect the connected bluetooth device using ExternalAccessory framework?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

I read the External Accessory framework couldn't find this one. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove paired Bluetooth devices on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755703/how-do-i-remove-paired-bluetooth-devices-on-ios)

Comment: @Eeshwar thanks for replying but its not the same, there people are talking about coreBluetooth framework, but  my query is related to External Accessory

Comment: Did you ever look further into this, I've also just looked at the EA documentation and there seems to be callbacks for when an accessory IS disconnected but not to manually disconnect it ourselves. I would think it would be in the same class as where you call 'configureAccessory'

Comment: @naomimichiko thanks for looking in to this. Yes, i tried to find the answer but as you said there is no way to connect or disconnect programatically using EA framework, though you will get the notifications when accessory is connected or disconnected.